# Notify CanExecute of command1 after command2 is executed

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have command1 which opens window that allows user to add item. After command1 is executed, I will change CanExecute so the button in the GUI goes gray.

After that the user can Add/Close (command2) the item. After the user Add/Close I would like to "un-gray" the button so user can add another item.

Problem is I don't know how to notify command1 then he can again execute itself. I have tried CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(); at the execute function of command2 but that won't call CanExecute from command1.

Is there a way to "un-gray" the button so it can be used again?

If anything is unclear please ask and I will provide additional information.

Here is the code of the command1:

```
    public class AddNewFilmWindowCommand : CommandBase<ViewModelCollection<FilmModel>>
{
    public override event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public AddNewFilmWindowCommand(ViewModelCollection<FilmModel> viewModelCollection)
        : base(viewModelCollection)
    {
    }

    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.ViewModel.NewItem == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public override void Execute(object item)
    {
        this.ViewModel.NewItem = new FilmModel();

        var onCanExecuteChanged = this.CanExecuteChanged;
        if (onCanExecuteChanged != null)
        {
            onCanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

command2 is pretty much the same but execute is of course different.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to AddNewFilmWindowCommand:

`internal void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(...);
}`

Call the new method from Command2 at the appropriate times.